# EF Core 7.0 is not updating single row with primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

First of all, I am trying to move the codebase to use DI with `AddDbContext`.
I am using Database-First approach and am NOT going to use Code-First and FluentAPI.

I have 3 questions and all of them are related.

There is an `id` column which is the real Identity primary key, and an `account` column which is unique. The `role_id` is a foriegn key to the Role table.

When I update a single User with its id, the following query is generated in `SaveChanges()`:

`UPDATE User SET id = @p4, account = @p5 ... WHERE role_id = @p6`

This query has 2 problems

1. EF uses the `role_id` in the where clause. *PK is expected
2. EF wants to update my `id` and `account` columns. *The behavior seems different than older versions

(1) What is the best way to make sure EF knows both the `id` and `account` are unqiue columns?

- I tried `[PrimaryKey(nameof(id))]` on class and `[Key]` attribute on `id`. Both did not help.
- The `[Index]` attribute has been changed in EF Core 7.0.

(2) I am wondering why this would happen. And how can I make sure EF is using the primary key, i.e. the `id` column, to update the records.

Also, throughout my trial and error, I am getting exceptions e.g.

> The properties 'MyUser.role_id', 'MyUser.id' are configured to use 'Identity' value generation and are mapped to the same table 'User', but only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' in 'OnModelCreating' for properties that should not use 'Identity'.

(3) Can someone explain why EF would consider the columns as Identity by default?

Here is the definition of my User entity.

```csharp
public class MyUser
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int id { get; set; }

  public string account { get; set; }
  
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]   // need this to tell EF is not doing its work correctly
  [ForeignKey(nameof(role))]
  public int? role_id { get; set; }
  public virtual StaffRole role { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the update code in controller:

```csharp
user.update_dtm = DateTime.Now;
DB.Attach(user);
DB.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
DB.Entry(user).Property(u => u.id).IsModified = false;       // so EF doesn't update my PK
DB.Entry(user).Property(u => u.account).IsModified = false;  // so EF doesn't update my unique key
DB.Entry(user).Property(u => u.create_dtm).IsModified = false;
await DB.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Most probably, you do have another `User` class somewhere in your code. Here, the table name `User` does not match the `MyUser` class, that's why changing attributes does not help.

Comment: Thank you @DmitryArestov. I was also aware of this and am pretty sure that's not the case. This is because changing the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` takes effect to "solve" the "double Identity" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed out the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)` method in my `DbContext`. In this method, there was a definition of Key using the wrong column `role_id` and caused the issue.